# How can I set mapping(address => bool) to all addresses default to true on constructor function?

Tags: solidity, mapping

```
contract Bogus {

    mapping(address => bool) internal iNeedItToBeTrueByDefault;

    function Bogus() {

        ???...
    }
}
```

Comment: if you can be more specific on requirement, workarounds might be suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't.**

What you can do is the inverse.

You keep track of the "blacklisted" addresses, instead of the whitelisted ones.